# my_zipcode_gem migration generators not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to the fact that this gem looks to be 3-4 years old and rails has changed how we do migrations. But I'm not too familiar with gems/generators. I'm trying to follow the instructions to do the instructions listed [here](https://github.com/midwire/my_zipcode_gem).

```
rails g my_zipcode_gem:models
rake db:migrate
rake zipcodes:update
```

However, when I do the first step I end up getting this:

```
/Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/my_zipcode_gem-0.1.3/lib/generators/my_zipcode_gem/models_generator.rb:35:in `create_migration': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:63:in `migration_template'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/my_zipcode_gem-0.1.3/lib/generators/my_zipcode_gem/models_generator.rb:36:in `create_migration'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:135:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/thammond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what I need to do to get that gem working? It provides exactly what I'm looking for in my app.

Thanks!

Edit: Adding the generation code:

```
module MyZipcodeGem
  class ModelsGenerator < Base
    include Rails::Generators::Migration

    source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

    def initialize(*args, &block)
      super
    end

    def generate_models
      # puts ">>> generate_zipcodes:"
    end

    def add_gems
      add_gem "mocha", :group => :test
    end

    def create_models
      template 'zipcode_model.rb', "app/models/zipcode.rb"
      template 'county_model.rb', "app/models/county.rb"
      template 'state_model.rb', "app/models/state.rb"
    end

    # Implement the required interface for Rails::Generators::Migration.
    # taken from http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/generators/active_record.rb
    def self.next_migration_number(dirname)
      if ActiveRecord::Base.timestamped_migrations
        Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
      else
        "%.3d" % (current_migration_number(dirname) + 1)
      end
    end

    def create_migration
      migration_template 'migration.rb', "db/migrate/create_my_zipcode_gem_models.rb"
    end

    def create_rakefile
      template 'zipcodes.rake', "lib/tasks/zipcodes.rake"
    end

  end
end

# /Users/cblackburn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/rails/generators/active_record/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is calling the migration using parameters that are no longer expected. You have two options:

1) fork the code, update it to use rails 4 conventions, and create a pull request on github. Assuming the owner is still active they will bring your code into the master and republish the gem. You would have help support the community and feel good about it in the process. There are plenty on here like myself who can help you with this.

2) Find another gem to do what you want, such as http://www.rubygeocoder.com/ which I've used several times and is awesome at doing location/zipcode problems

Comment: I think I'll do both - rubygeocoder for now, but I think it'd be great to get this gem back up to par as well :)